# How to use haproxy to load backend1 ONLY if backend2 is dead?

Tags: haproxy

After a lot of search, i can not find a very basic and simple way to use backend server 2 when **ONLY IF backend 1 is dead**.

Here is my current configuration:

```
frontend www
    bind *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    default_backend varnish-1

backend varnish-1
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth skonsoft:SECRET_PASSWORD     # Credentials for HAProxy Statistic report page.
    balance roundrobin          # Load balancing will work in round-robin process.
    option httpchk
    option  httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie SRV_ID prefix
    server varnish-1 192.168.1.91:80 check cookie
    server varnish-2 192.168.1.71:80 check cookie
```

As you can see, currently i'm using **default_backend varnish-1** and  hoping that it will do the job... But it does not work. When I put Varnish-2 server ON, Haproxy use the 2 backend servers...

My problem is very simple: How to configure Haproxy to use backend-2 server **IF and ONLY IF backend-1 is down**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the backup server as exactly that:

```
server varnish-1 192.168.1.91:80 check cookie
server varnish-2 192.168.1.71:80 check cookie backup
```

That will then only be used if no "regular" servers are available.

If you have multiple servers marked as `backup` then only the first of those that is available will be used.

This scenario is often called a "sorry server setup" because the backup server could be used to serve a "Sorry, we're down" placeholder page.